# facebook sdk framework missing from ios application

Tags: ios, facebook, api

i making iphone app using **xcode 4.1** and in that i am using Facebook SDKs for the Facebook integration. but when i try to open that project in the **xcode 4.3.3** then it gives me that error face book. SDKs framework not found in your application.

What should i do to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Does your framework still appear in your project settings > Build phases > Link binary with libraries ? If yes, try to delete it and re-add it.

Comment: frame work is not there over there.there is no framework available in that framework list .facebook.sdkframework

Comment: Is your framework added to your project ? (somewhere in your files in the left bar)

Comment: no i just using the facebook with JSON using that

Comment: when i running this in xcode 4.3.3 then all facebook sdk file in that folder are missing and becomes red

Comment: Select all the red files, remove them, and follow the answer I posted

Comment: how to get facebook.frame work

Comment: okay i do that but it will give me these error..

Comment: Command /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1                                         these error i get

Comment: You said it work in Xcode 4.1, just use the same file you used there. Or go over there : http://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Comment: What's the error just above that ? There should be 2 lines of error

Answer (score 0):

Add the framework to your project (drag it from the finder to the left bar of Xcode, select copy if you want), then go to your project settings > Build phases > Link binary with libraries, click the "+" button, search for your framework and add it. It should be then included in your app.

Comment: yes i doing same thng but the facebook framework is not over there

Comment: Command /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: Did you add the framework to your project by dragging it into the left bar of Xcode ? If yes, then try to drag it from the left bar to the *Link binary with Libraries*

Comment: in my leftbar there not facebook sdk framework is there so can you send to me that framework

Comment: The link is in my comment on your question

Comment: @RaviVaghela please do not try to edit my answer to post a screenshot about your problem. Edit your own question. I will stop helping because you don't follow at all StackOverflow's guidelines. You post multiple times the same question and comments, and you don't make an effort with your english.